# Flask sql alchemy : Join between two tables of different types

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

is it possible to join 2 tables using `uuid`

```py
session.query(TokenDebitHistory)\
.join(coupons,TokenDebitHistory.sr_no == uuid.UUID(coupons.c.trans_debit_id)`
```

as i have declared `sr_no` as `primary key` field which is also of type `UUID`

> Error:

`boolean value of this clause is not defined !`

Comment: i am converting `coupons.c.trans_debit_id` to `UUID` type but its throwing an error

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: What is your DB dialect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `join` function, it will finally be sent to your DB Engine as an SQL Query. Sending `uuid.UUID(coupons.c.trans_debit_id)` will certainly send a query

But this query will not be correctly interpreted by your RDBMS.

You need to do this conversion at DB level (i.e **as a part of the SQL Query**).

For this purpose, you should use a `CAST` statement. In SQL Alchemy you can use the `cast` function. And you should cast this column to the UUID type of the DB dialect you use.

Here is an example *using the PostgreSQL dialect* which might be a different one in your case.

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy import cast

select(TokenDebitHistory) \
.join(coupons,TokenDebitHistory.sr_no == cast(coupons.c.trans_debit_id, UUID))
```

Which will be compiled to this SQL query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM TokenDebitHistory 
JOIN coupons
On TokenDebitHistory.sr_no = CAST(coupons.trans_debit_id AS UUID)
```